# What are the problems of my box size determination?

Tags: css

```
<html>
  <body>
        <style>
            #div11 {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="div1">
            <div id="div11"></div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In above case I think heights of ***div1*** and ***div11*** both are 0. Below is my inference.

There is a cyclic dependence of box size between ***div1*** and ***div11***: Generated box ***b1*** of ***div1*** is containing block of generated box ***b11*** of ***div11***. ***b1***'s height is initial value **auto**. So ***b1***'s height depends on ***b11***'s. ***b11***'s height is specified as a percentage value which depends on its containing block that is ***b1***.

The closed dependence is resolved in below way. 
Section 10.5 of CSS 2.1 prescribes: " If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value (of the element's height) computes to 'auto' ", so b11's height computes to **auto**.

 After resolving closed dependence box size is determined in such way: ***b11*** has not content so its height is 0 according to rule 4 in section 10.6.3 of the specification. Then ***b1***'s auto height computes to 0.

But the actual rendering in browser is different. What are the problems of my inference? Do I misunderstand some rules or ignore some semantics in the specification? Thank for your help very much.

Comment: In your code, div11 is set to be 100% of the height of div1. Since the height of div1 is 0, the height of div11 is 0, because 100% of 0 = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quoting the correct part of the specification. The reason that's not what you experience is because by not specifying a DOCTYPE. you've put the browser in quirks mode. So the browser is behaving quirkily different from the CSS standand, and what you have to look at instead is the [Quirks mode standard](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/).

In this case the relevant quirk is [3.5. The percentage height calculation quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-percentage-height-calculation-quirk). Basically, for your example, the algorithm loops until it hits the initial containing block, and then sets `div11` to 100% of the height of that, i.e. it takes the height of the viewport.